# HP Proliant DL360p gen8 Unrecoverable Media Error. Amber lights on 3 disks

Tags: hard-drive, raid-5, hp-proliant

I have HP Proliant DL360p gen8. 4 disk on RAID 5, 3 of them have amber light on them. I did `chkdsk` on my virtual machines none reported any error. Am I able to fix it without buying and replacing disks? If no, then do I need to replace all 3 disks?

POST Message:

> SLOT 0 HP Smart Array p420i Controller (1GB v5.42) 1 Logical Drive 1716-Slot 0 Drive Array - Unrecoverable Media Errors Detected on Drives during previous Rebuild or background Surface Analysis (ARM) scan. Errors will be fixed automatically when the sector(s) are overwritten. Backup and Restore recommended. 1720-Slot 0 Drive Array - S.M.A.R.T. Hard Drive(s) Detect Imminent Failure: port 1l: Box 1:Bays 1,2,3 Do not replace drive unless all other drives in the array are on-line!

Comment: The message seems to imply that "Bays 1,2,3" need replacing.

Comment: Aye. 1) Backup. 2) check backup.  3) Make sure your systems gets frequest backups since the drives in bays 1,2 and 3 report that that are near failing.  For more information read up on SMART. It is not proliant of RAID specific.

Comment: Unless there's some magic way to shrink the RAID 5 to not use those 3 disks, it looks like you will need to do this ASAP. You may need to do this one at a time though, as RAID5 can only handle one missing disk (at a time). As other comment says though - backup! if one of those disks fail while rebuilding the raid, you could be up a messy creek.